# Ruby: Returning a ruby class value through another class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm coding in Ruby and I've got 2 classes, Items and ItemTypes. Items belongs_to ItemTypes and ItemTypes has_many Items.
ItemTypes has a name whereas Items only have an ItemType integer.
How can I return the “name” of the ItemType through the Item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your model is something like that:

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :item_type
end

class ItemType < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :items
end
```

And for a given item, you want the `name` of its item_type. So here is what you are looking for:

```
# item = Item.find(1)
item.item_type.name
```

Comment: Change `<%= s.item_type %>` into `<%= s.item_type.name %>` I suppose?

Comment: And you should replace `Item.all` by `Item.all.includes(:item_type)` to avoid N+1 requests. You'll find more info on this here: https://semaphoreci.com/blog/2017/08/09/faster-rails-eliminating-n-plus-one-queries.html

Comment: You're welcome. Don't hesitate to validate the answer if it worked for you.